# Can not extract part of the string with binary operators in Elixir

Tags: string, binary, elixir

Hello I was trying to understand how to work with binaries in Elixir and I was trying to parse a string

```
"2018-04-07 13:00:00.000000"
```

I wanted to get they year part and I did the following

```
date = "2018-04-07 13:00:00.000000"
<< d::size(80), rest::binary >> = date
```

now when I try to get rest I get everything after the date including space

```
" 13:00:00.000000"
```

but if I try to get d I don't really understand what I get but the output is the following

```
237007314493411930484791
```

Can you guys please help understand what is going.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to use `binary-size` as follows: `<< d::binary-size(10), rest::binary >> = date`

Following excerpt of the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1-types) should clarify accordingly:

> A bitstring is made of many segments and each segment has a   type.
>   There are 9 types used in bitstrings:
>     - `integer`
>     - `float`
>     - `bits` (alias for `bitstring`)
>     - `bitstring`
>     - `binary`
>     - `bytes` (alias for `binary`)
>     - `utf8`
>     - `utf16`
>     - `utf32`   When no type is specified, the default is `integer`

For instance, `<< d::integer-size(80), rest::binary >> = date` would have given you the same result as you reported.

Answer (score 5):

While the answer provided by Kevin Johnson perfectly explains how to handle binaries, I will post the explanation of what really happened.

The binary in Erlang (and hence in Elixir) might be created using ASCII values for chars:

```rb
iex|1 ▶ <<50, 48>>
#⇒ "20"
```

When you pattern matched to `size(80)` you actually pattern matched to 10 positions of the integer in 256-base. Basically, this is what happened:

```rb
iex|2 ▶ <<a1::size(8), a2::size(8), a3::size(8),
          a4::size(8), a5::size(8), a6::size(8),
          a7::size(8), a8::size(8), a9::size(8),
          a10::size(8), _ :: binary>> = "2018-04-07 13..."
#⇒ "2018-04-07 13..."
```

Let’s check our values (yes, the array of integers is printed out as a bitstring whenever possible, note *single quotes*):

```rb
iex|3 ▶ [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10] 
#⇒ '2018-04-07'
```

OK, so far so good. Let’s now get the result out of the above integers. It would be:

```rb
a10 * 1 + a9 * 256 + a8 * 256² + ...
```

or, using the limited Elixir arithmetical abilities:

```rb
iex|4 ▶ [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10]
...|4 ▷ |> Enum.reverse
...|4 ▷ |> Enum.with_index
...|4 ▷ |> Enum.reduce(0, fn {e, i}, acc ->
...|4 ▷                     # ⇓⇓⇓ exact integer i-power of 256 ⇓⇓⇓
...|4 ▷      acc + e * Enum.reduce(List.duplicate(256, i), 1, &Kernel.*/2)
...|4 ▷ end)
#⇒ 237007314493411930484791
```

This is exactly what you yielded when have asked to pattern match first 10 positions to 256-based 10-digit number.

Comment: Great explanation of what happened.  Very helpful!